# Returning and iterable collection using yield in scala

Tags: scala, loops, yield-return, yield-keyword

I have a DateTime and TimeSpan class in Scala (assume that the < and + operators work as they should).  I'm trying to define a 'range' function that takes a start/stop time and a timespan for stepping. In C# I would do this with a yield, and I think I should be able to do the same in Scala... except I'm getting a strange error.

On the 'yield t' line, I get "Illegal start of statement".

```
  def dateRange(from : DateTime, to : DateTime, step : TimeSpan) =
  {
      // not sure what the list'y way of doing this is
    var t = from

    while(t < to)
    {
      yield t; // error: illegal start of statement
      t = t + step
    }
  }
```

Looking at this code, I am curious about 2 things:
1) what did I do wrong?
2) the code as written is very imperative (uses a var t, etc).  What's the more functional way to do this in Scala that is reasonably fast?

Thanks!

Comment: `yield` in Scala has nothing whatsoever to do with `yield` in C# (or Python). Furthermore, Scala has no equivalent to it -- look up the many questions about Scala, Python, yield and generators. And, of course, look up the questions about what `yield` actually does.

Comment: I did, and I was confused.  Debilski's answer told me all I needed to know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
def dateRange(from : DateTime, to : DateTime, step : TimeSpan): Iterator[DateTime] =
  Iterator.iterate(from)(_ + step).takeWhile(_ <= to)
```

Comment: If I could give you a +1000, I would.  That's awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of @Debilski solution with joda time periods:

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Period}

def dateRange(from: DateTime, to: DateTime, step: Period): Iterator[DateTime] =
  Iterator.iterate(from)(_.plus(step)).takeWhile(!_.isAfter(to))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, `yield` is a special statement for for-loops.

I don't know C#, but from what I understand, I think the easiest for you is to use `collection.immutable.NumericRange.Exclusive[DateTime]` or `collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[DateTime]`, depending on whether your interval is exclusive or inclusive.

For that to work, you will need to create an instance of `Integral[DateTime]` which defines the arithmetics for type `DateTime`.

Comment: Well, `Integral` is kind of stupid to implement for `DateTime` it seems. The other approach with `Iterator.iterate` is much better.